# NServiceBus logging to custom log

Tags: nservicebus

I have noticed that when I call the /install flag on NServiceBus.host.exe an event log source is created under the Application event log. The trouble is, we have configured NServiceBus L4N to write events to the same source but under a custom event log.

This causes a problem because if we create the source under our custom event log the installation fails (NserviceBus installer throws a System.ArgumentException: Source blah already exists on the local computer).

So how can we stop the NServiceBus installer from trying to create the event source under the Application event log?

We are using NServiceBus 3.0.1.0

Thanks

**EDIT** - Full stacktrace

```
Creating EventLog source blah in log Application...

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ArgumentException: Source blah already exists
on the local computer.

The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning.
Restoring event log to previous state for source blah
.
Service blah is being removed from the system...
Service blah was successfully removed from the system
.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed. ---> System.ArgumentException: Source blah already exists on the local computer.
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventSourceCreationData sourceData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at Topshelf.Internal.Hosts.HostServiceInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver) 
in d:\dev\open-source\topshelf\src\Topshelf\Internal\Hosts\HostServiceInstaller.cs:line 120
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)
   at Topshelf.Internal.Hosts.HostServiceInstaller.Register() in d:\dev\open-source\topshelf\src\Topshelf\Internal\Hosts\HostServiceInstaller.cs:line 61
   at Topshelf.Internal.Actions.InstallServiceAction.Do(IRunConfiguration configuration) in d:\dev\open-source\topshelf\src\Topshelf\Internal\Actions\InstallServiceAction.cs:line 42
   at Topshelf.Runner.Host(IRunConfiguration configuration, String[] args) in d:\dev\open-source\topshelf\src\Topshelf\Runner.cs:line 70
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\nsb.masterbuild1\src\hosting\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\Program.cs:line 122
```

Comment: NServiceBus is only logging to the console/file so I'm pretty sure that this is not related to the actual logging. I'm not 100% sure but I think that a event source is created when you install a windows service?

Comment: It could be that topshelf is creating the source automatically. I need to dig a bit deeper

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever find out what was causing it?

Comment: Hi Nils, sorry we worked around the issue by naming our custom event log sources differently. You may get more joy *logging* this problem on the yahoo group http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/ (no pun intended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem only occurs if we configure Log4net with the same event source name as the endpoint name.

So we can have use different source name in our event log (in our case, `<endpoint-name>.l4n`). This will work around the issue for now.

Comment: I ended up with the same work-around. I wish one could decide which event source NServiceBus (or topshelf) is using.

Answer (score 2):

If things go really pear-shaped, you can find the event log sources in your registry

```
HKLM/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/services/eventlog/...
```

From there, you can manually delete the event log sources that you no longer want.

Comment: Jarrett the issue is not going to be solved with a manual action. All our deployments are automated.